# counting number of rows in a table that are true between two timedates

Tags: python

I've got this table:

```
 IdNum                  BeginDate                      Exitdate
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
123                    2022-06-13 09:03               2022-06-13 22:12
633                    2022-06-13 08:15               2022-06-13 13:09
389                    2022-06-13 10:03               2022-06-13 18:12
665                    2022-06-13 08:30               2022-06-13 10:12
```

I want to get data for each 15 min of the day to know if the person (IdNum) was in the process.

For example: I want to know how many IdNum were in the process between 18:00 and 18:15.

According to the table above I should get: 2

Because only IdNum 123 and IdNum 389 were in the process during that 15 minutes of the day.

Can I write a function or something that receive that table above and returns a new table with 96 new column(for each 15 min of the day) and for each row (IdNum) you get True of False if he were in the process during that time?

Example:

```
 IdNum      BeginDate               Exitdate                00:00 - 00:15       18:00 - 18:15      etc etc..
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123         2022-06-13 09:03        2022-06-13 22:12         FALSE              TRUE
633         2022-06-13 08:15        2022-06-13 13:09         FALSE              FALSE
389         2022-06-13 10:03        2022-06-13 18:12         FALSE              TRUE
665         2022-06-13 08:30        2022-06-13 10:12         FALSE              FALSE
```

OR maybe it is easier to write a function that receives 3 variables:

a table, a start time (exmp: 18:00), end time (exmp: 18:15) and it returns: 2 (number of IdNum's that were present between those times).

what is easier to do on Python? is that possible? can you help me with a lead or something of what is the better way to do it on Python? The first one or the second one I presented above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here my solution, you will have a Dataframe with Id as idex and booleans for the hours where the employees were here like you've shown in your first example.

```
import pandas as pd

#Your initial Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([[123,"2022-06-13 09:03", "2022-06-13 22:12"],[633, "2022-06-13 08:15", "2022-06-13 13:09"]], columns=['IdNum', 'BeginDate', 'Exitdate'])

#The dictionnary where I'll stock the result
dico_res = {}
for i in range(df.shape[0]):

  #I define a range of dates to know if your enter and exit is in the range
  enter = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[i]["BeginDate"])
  exit = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[i]["Exitdate"])
  start = pd.to_datetime(enter.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
  range_15_minutes = pd.date_range(start=start, end=end,freq="15min")
  list_boolean, idx = [], []
  
  for date in range(len(range_15_minutes)-1):
    if enter >= range_15_minutes[date] and enter < range_15_minutes[date+1]:
      list_boolean.append(True)
      
    elif exit >= range_15_minutes[date] and exit < range_15_minutes[date+1]:
      list_boolean.append(True)
    
    elif exit < range_15_minutes[date] or enter > range_15_minutes[date]:
        list_boolean.append(False)
    
    else:
      list_boolean.append(True)
      
    idx.append(range_15_minutes[date].strftime("%H:%M") + "-" + range_15_minutes[date+1].strftime("%H:%M"))

  dico_res[df.loc[i]["IdNum"]]=list_boolean

dataframe_solution = pd.DataFrame(dico_res, index=idx).T
```

Comment: Hey Virgaux, Thanks a lot for your answer. Can you explain to me just how I import the data that I have (in excel) into python to show it like you did as 'df' at the begining?

thanks a lot!

Comment: So if you have an excel at the beginning you can use [pandas.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html). If you have some problem I recommend use to save your excel as csv than use [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

Comment: also, it says NAMEERROR: name 'pd' is not defined. I supposte to import pandas? can you help me with how to do that? thanks a lot. sorry, Im new to python..

Comment: You can install pandas with `pip install pandas` and then do import pandas as pd.